# import several databases with powershell

Tags: database, powershell, azure, import

how can I import several databases with powershell??

Currently this is my code :

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\util\utilConnection.ps1;
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\util\utilDate.ps1;
#Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\logging\Logging_Functions.ps1;
Import-Module AzureRM.sql

$TIMESTAMP = getTimeStamp;

#$LogPath = getPathLog;
#$logFileName = "prueba_jobDatabaseBackup.log";

#Log-Start -LogPath $LogPath -LogName $logFileName -ScriptVersion "1.5"

#return;

#Login-AzureRmAccount
loginRMAccount;

#Set subscription Azure
itsits;

Write-Output "";

#Create credential Source DB Server (QA)
#$myPasswordDB = ConvertTo-SecureString $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_QA -AsPlainText -Force;
#$myCredentialDB = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_QA, $myPasswordDB);
#$sqlCredential = Get-Credential -Credential $myCredentialDB;

#Create credential Source DB Server (Prod)
$myPasswordDB = ConvertTo-SecureString $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_QA -AsPlainText -Force;
$myCredentialDB = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_QA, $myPasswordDB);
$sqlCredential = Get-Credential -Credential $myCredentialDB;

$resourceGroup = "resGroupDB";
$serverName = "domserverqa";
$database = "mirroring_dbdom_coquimbo(2018-01-09-07:00)";
$primarykey = $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BACKUP_KEY; #strdatabasebackup
$StorageUri = "https://strdatabasebackup.blob.core.windows.net/strdatabasebackupblob/(2018-01-09-07:00)dbdom_coquimbo.bacpac";
#$sqlCredential = getCredentialSQLServerQA; #SQL Server target

$SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_QA = getSQLServerFullNameAzureQA;
$TIMEOUT = 300;

$importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport –ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup –ServerName $serverName –DatabaseName $database –StorageKeytype StorageAccessKey –StorageKey $primarykey -StorageUri $StorageUri -AdministratorLogin $sqlCredential.UserName –AdministratorLoginPassword $sqlCredential.Password –Edition Basic –ServiceObjectiveName basic -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 2147483648 # 2GB -> 2 * 1024 MB -> 2 * 1024 * 1024 KB -> 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 Bytes

$importStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink;

while ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
{
    $importStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink;        
    Write-Output ".";
    [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(2000);            
}

[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(4000);            

Write-Output "";                 
$QUERY = "ALTER DATABASE [$($database)] MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL (name = [ElasticPoolDOMQA(Basic)]))";
Write-Output $QUERY;
Invoke-Sqlcmd -AbortOnError -EncryptConnection -ConnectionTimeout $TIMEOUT -Database 'master' -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_QA -Username "prueba" -Password "prueba._" -Query $QUERY;
```

Actually it works but I have several databases and I have to change the names one by one and run the script

How can I do to add several databases within the script?
the databases are on the same server.

Comment: Instead of changing the names one by one, why can't you create a loop that iterates through each of the database names and runs your import commands for each database?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do but I do not understand how to do it

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you don't understand? How to download a db from Azure? How to query the SQL server for a list of databases? As it stands, you have a very broad question that can branch into many different possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be like below

```
$serverName = "domserverqa";
$databases = (Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ServerName $serverName).DatabaseName
$Backupdatatime = "Standard time of the backup for all databases" # E.g. "2018-01-09-07:00"
foreach($database in $databases)
{
    $primarykey = $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BACKUP_KEY; #strdatabasebackup
    # Assuming strdatabase as a standard name given to the storage accounts and other databases follow the naming conventions.
    $StorageUri = "https://" + $database + "backup" + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + $database + "backupblob" + "/" + "(" + $Backupdatatime + ")" + $databases + ".bacpac"

    #Further actions.....
}
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to list the steps that you should take to get your code in a more manageable state.

1. Refactor your database import code to be contained within a function. This will make your code MUCH more manageable.
2. Retrieve the list of SQL databases from the Azure SQL server, and store them in an array. (Optionally, you could hard code the array with the database values). You can use the [Get-AzureSQLDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azuresqldatabase?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) command to retrieve said list of databases.
3. Iterate through each element in your array and execute your importdb function for each database. Something like this:

   $databases = "testdb1", "testdb2", "testdb3"

   foreach ($database in $databases)
   {
      ImportDb -database $database
   }

Comment: thanks for answering,
try with foreach but I do not know which part I fail, I do not find